# Running .Net application on visual studio code in MacBook pro

Tags: c#, .net, macos, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I am doing C# programming in Visual Studio Code in MacBook Pro, so whenever I run the application, a dotnet process is left in the memory, when I open the Activity Monitor the memory is not disposed, and the CPU is running at 100% even after the debugging is stopped. Is something wrong with my code or is there anything else that I should be doing while writing c# code in Mac OS. Please let me know, right now after every run I am opening activity monitor and force quitting the process.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to have [.Net Core](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/macos) and [C# extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.csharp) installed.

The High CPU consumption is often caused by an issue in an extension.

You can open the Process Explorer using `Help>Open Process Explorer` to view the list of running VS Code processes running in real-time where you'll find what is causing High CPU consumption where extensions are executed by the `Extension Host` process.

If the High CPU consumption isn't caused by VS Code then it's probably your code and you'll have to optimize it.

You can check the Performance Issues Wiki for more details [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/wiki/Performance-Issues)